# What benefit is added by creating a new delegate when handling an event?

Tags: blazor

What value is added by this:

```
<MyControl ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<int>>>(ServerReload))">
```

versus this:

```
<MyControl ServerData="@ServerReload">
```

where the handler is:

```
private async Task<TableData<int>> ServerReload(TableState state) {...}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) uses the second method and makes no mention of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'benefit' because there is no difference.

The following all compiles:

```cs
var f1 = new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<int>>>(ServerReload));
Func<TableState, Task<TableData<int>>> f2 = ServerReload;    
f2 = f1;
```

The second form is just a shorthand form available since C# 2. But it is compiled as if it was the first long form, a Func is a delegate and needs to be new-ed.

You get the exact same IL code so the only difference is in readability. The second short form is of course very much preferable.

In C# 1 you had to write:

```
MyDelegateType myDelegateVar = new MyDelegateType(MethodName);
```

from C# 2 onwards you can write the same as

```
MyDelegateType myDelegateVar = MethodName;
```

Comment: Well, IMHO there is a difference. E.g. Style. Readability. Maintainability. Etc.

Comment: Yes, I  thought that was obvious. Which make the exact answer: a negative readability value is added.